# Modular Objects with conflicting implementations

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a game framework that would allow users to use multiple mods/plugins to add additional features to the game.

For the remainder of the post, I'll use the following definitions:

`mod`: code that requires changes to both the client and the server. For example, adding a new packet to the protocol.

`plugin`: code that changes existing functionality without requiring a change on the other side. For example, adding a remote management interface to the server, or allows the client more fine-grained controls over sound and audio quality.

This question relates to both of these aspects, however I'll be focusing on `mods` as they seem to be giving me the biggest trouble.

Let's say I provide a default player class called `Player` that models a Player's character. Let's say, for this particular server, the server operator wants to include 2 `mods`, `Foo` and `Bar`, both of which are written by different people.

Both `Foo` and `Bar` need to add additional functionality to the `Player` class. `Foo` needs a method `doFoo`, and `Bar` needs a method `doBar`. Both actual implementations are included *somehow* by the mod developers (probably in a different class).

One solution I've considered is using Reflection, and modifying the class at runtime, extending specific mod interfaces. Something like

```
public interface FooPlayer {
    void doFoo();
}

public interface BarPlayer {
    void doBar();
}

public class FooPlayerImplementation implements FooPlayer {
    public void doFoo() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class BarPlayerImplementation implements BarPlayer {
    public void doBar() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class FooLoader {

    public void onLoad() {
        SomeManager.findPlayerClass()
                   .implementInterface(FooPlayer.class, FooPlayerImplementation.class);
    }
}

public class BarLoader {
    public void onLoad() {
        SomeManager.findPlayerClass()
                   .implementInterface(BarPlayer.class, BarPlayerImplementation.class);
    }
}
```

Where at runtime, it would inject the `Player` class with the implementations from `Foo` and `Bar`, and make it implement `FooPlayer` and `BarPlayer`. But then we have issues where two different mods add the same method signature in their own interface (which could be resolved by prepending the class name to the method, but then we're going down a very dark rabbit hole).

Another thing that I had thought about briefly was just going event-driven to an insane degree, so that developers didn't *need* to do something like this, but that opens an equally hair can of worms, as well as not providing the amount of control a developer might need.

But I'd **REALLY** like to avoid reflection if at all possible.

I've seen AspectJ and aspect-oriented programming, and it looks like it *may* work, but I don't have any experience to tell.

The questions I have are:

1. Is there a way to get this sort of functionality in an OOP way?
2. Is there a way to do this with the standard Java SE library?
3. Could AOP accomplish this?

**Considerations**: If any of these are wrong or misguided, please let me know.

1. I don't think that inheritance will work because there could be multiple mods that want to extend the functionality of `Player`, and all `Player`s would be subject to all of the `mods`. There couldn't be a `FooPlayer` and a `FooBarPlayer` at the same time. If `n` mods extend the Player functionality, than the Player must have `n` components.
2. The decorator pattern won't really work I think because manual intervention would be required by the operator (who may or may not know anything about programming) to weave the implementations together.

Something like

```
public class FooBarStaminaMagickaPlayer implements Player, Foo, Bar, Stamina, Magicka
```

3. If possible, I would like to avoid having each mod developer have a mapping within their code to keep track of things.

For example, something like

```
public class StaminaMapper {
    private final Map<Player, Stamina> playerStaminaMap;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't all players in a game have the same set of mods enabled?

Comment: @COMEFROM I've updated the OP a bit

Comment: I think having mods as subclasses of the Player class conflicts with your goal. Perhaps you could provide a PlayerExtension class (or interface) for mods.

Comment: @COMEFROM none of the code in the OP suggests subclassing the player. That was the reason i updated the op in the first place. How would a PlayerExtension class help?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question through after the edit. I guess my suggestion falls into the category "not giving developers the amount of control they might need".

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely feeling like all of your options will take you down a "very dark rabbit hole" because you are already in a rabbit hole, and the proper solution is to step back out of the hole and consider a new direction.

Here is a link on how many games are developed which might address your concerns indirectly but more fundamentally.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

This quote I think addresses your exact roadblock:

> An ECS follows the Composition over inheritance principle that allows greater flexibility in defining entities where every object in a game's scene is an entity (e.g. enemies, bullets, vehicles, etc.). Every Entity consists of one or more components which add additional behavior or functionality. Therefore the behavior of an entity can be changed at runtime by adding or removing components. This eliminates the ambiguity problems of deep and wide inheritance hierarchies that are difficult to understand, maintain and extend.

and

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013

---

Ok this is my attempt to give you an example of how to solve the problem using ECS. This can be greatly improved upon. The purpose is to show off the design, not the details of how to make it work optimally.

```
abstract class Component
{
    public string ComponentType { get; } // implements some identifier which modders can generate/register for new components
}

class Position : Component { }
class Velocity : Component { }
class Health : Component { }

abstract class Entity
{
    public List<Component> Components;
    public abstract T GetComponentOfType<T>();
    public abstract Component GetComponentById(string Id);
}

class MovementSystem
{
    public static void Execute(Position p, Velocity v)
    {
        // do stuff with p and v
    }
}


// When it comes time to add new components, all you do is add the modder's new component, system, registration, and any other mechanism for incrementing the game loop.

class Stamina : Component { }

class StaminaSystem
{
    void Execute(Position p, Velocity v, Stamina s)
    {
        // do stuff with p and v and s
    }
}

class StaminaSystemLoop
{
    bool IsEntityEquipedWithCorrectComponentsForThisSystem(Entity e);

    void Increment(Entity e)
    {
         StaminaSystem.Execute(e.GetComponentOfType<Position>(), e.GetComponentOfType<Velocity>(), e.GetComponentOfType<Stamina>());
    }
}



class GameLoop
{
    void Increment(List<Entity> gameEntities)
    {
        foreach(var e in gameEntities)
        {
             // Detect if entity is a match for any given system.
             // Execute the system with the components using GetComponentOfType.
             //
             // The installation process for the mod will need to add the detection logic and the execution logic.
             // So this is where you have to get creative about it. E.g.:
             if(StaminaSystemLoop.IsEntityEquipedWithCorrectComponentsForThisSystem(e))
                  StaminaSystemLoop.Increment(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Player` had a component `Health`, how then would I deal with a mod that wants to add a `Stamina` component, and another mod that wants to add a `Magicka` component in the calling code? I'd like to avoid something like `(Stamina) player.getComponent("stamina");`

Comment: That's a good question and one I do not have an immediate answer for. It seems to me if you want that kind of freedom for your modders, you would have to allow modders not only the capability of mixing/matching predefined components to create entirely new entities, but the capability to create entirely new components and therefore new systems to handle those components.

Comment: At which point I would suggest inheritance as a possibility. It seems to me it would be fairly easy in ECS to extend player to contain a new Stamina component, and extend the Attack system to reduce stamina and extend the move system to reduce stamina recovery at one rate while extending the idle system to set stamina recovery at a new rate.

Comment: But then we get to the same problem that I mentioned [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317771/modular-objects-with-conflicting-implementations/318062?noredirect=1#comment674373_318031), where we have two different mods that want to extend the `Player`, a `StaminaPlayer` that has a `Stamina` component, and a `MagickaPlayer` that has a `Magicka` component. Because all players have to have all of the same components, I can't have them separate. Stamina and Magicka are just examples I felt would illustrate the idea succinctly; in reality, players in the game would have neither.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand clearly the requirements. If modder A creates mod A which includes the Stamina component and the extensions to the systems which handle Stamina logic, and modder B creates mod B which includes the Magicka component and the extensions to the systems which handle Magicka logic, do I understand correctly that that server operator will install both and that users will have to choose which or none they wish to use? If so, the ECS design handles this, since the player objects which are not StaminaPlayers could be ignored when run through the extended systems.

Comment: The server operator would install both mods, and all `Player`s would be affected (I've cleared that up a bit in the OP). If the intent of the operator is for `Player`s to have both a `Stamina` and `Magicka` component, then all players must have both. If later, the operator wanted to install a new mod, `Factions`, which had a `Faction` component representing which cities or towns Players were loyal to, then the Player would have a `Stamina`, `Magicka`, and `Faction` component.

Comment: I see. In simple cases like Factions which probably don't mix with other systems, simply introduce a new System and your done. In complex cases like Stamina which do mix with other systems, you only have two broad options: 1) make sure only one mod is applied at a time so modderB can extend modderA's system extensions, or 2) allow  a way to introduce new systems without altering existing ones. One way this can be done is by designing your systems as components. Any time a system executes its primary functions, it also executes any registered sub systems.

Comment: A problem I see with the first option is, let's say you have those 2 mods, `Stamina` and `Magicka`. Since only one can be used at a time, we'll make `MagickaAuthor` extend `Stamina` so that they're both there. But then the operator decides that they want only `Magicka` and not `Stamina`. For the second option, do you have any examples I could look at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39594/discussion-between-zymus-and-price-jones).

Answer (score 1):

There is one other solution. It may slow down code (not as bad as reflection though) .

Everything has an interface. The classes will only do function composition: pipe returns to parameters to returns, etc.  All prameters and instance variables are interfaces.

A mod or plugin is just a package  of implementions for interfaces. Make one mod called defaults. Put this in its own package. That way, the rest is API code.

Mod loading has to be done. Now a container can inject classes in, and look for mod folders.

There can be a list of all mods in a file, in priority order. With a conflict, the first mod listed will be the one used in the container.

I recomand a dependency injection framework for this. I would also recomand using gaurd clauses. with messages in the exeptions for parameter valid ranges. Just because glitches, and exploits would be made.

Comment: One problem with this is that, for conflicts, I can't just use a *pick the first* strategy. The operators intend on having all functionality within the mods usable. It needs to be a *merge*.

Comment: Blending can be a class that implements a interface. It will also implement the interface. Then average the results from the list for each method and return that. The class can be called mod merging.

Answer (score 0):

I will only respond to your first question since I don't have enough experience to pronounce myself on AOP.

My favourite way to extend a complete (understand non-abstract) existing piece of code is to use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Let's say this is what you defined as a minimal working player for your framework. The most important point is that every public method in `PlayerImpl` must be inherited from `Player` (see below why):

```
public interface Player {
    void doAction();
}

public final class PlayerImpl implements Player {
    @Override
    public void doAction() {
        //do action
    }
}
```

It is then possible for mods developers to safely (without altering the existing) add behaviour to a player using the decorator pattern:

```
public interface Foo {
    void foo();
}

public final class FooPlayer implements Player, Foo {
    private final Player origin;

    public FooPlayer(Player origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAction() {
        origin.doAction(); //or define totally new behaviour when needed (typically for a plugin)
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        // put special mod behaviour
    }
}
```

And then in usage, instances of `FooPlayer` are always usable by your framework (because they inherit from `Player`) and the mod developer can also use the specific behaviour in its code when needed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooPlayer p1 = new FooPlayer(MyGame.provideNewPlayer());
    MyGame.registerNewPlayer(p1); //still compatible with what you provide altough holding a reference of FooPlayer
    p1.doAction();
    p1.foo();
}
```

Comment: This results in the same issue we were in before I edited the question I think. Where there's a mod `Foo` and a mod `Bar` and both of them make different changes to the `Player` class.

Comment: @Zymus The `PlayerImpl` class is immutable and isn't modified neither by `Foo` nor by `Bar`. Both can make different changes in two different classes (no conflict).

Comment: Bit would the game engine not have 3x the `Player`s registered then? Because there'd be a new object for each mod, I believe i would also have to have some sort of synchronizer when saving them for example.

Comment: If a mod adds new behaviour, there's no way (except maybe reflection) to "teach" it to your existing framework. It means that the mod has to manage every aspect of the behaviour it adds. Example: you can design your framework to be able to save instances of `Player`, but the specifics of a `FooPlayer`'s instance must be saved **by the mod** because your framework can't guess what the mod added (except, as said, by reflection).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any form of inheritance is going to work reliably with this. As you've identified, you're going to have conflicts, and you'll be creating a brittle/fragile set of classes. If you change your base class (for whatever reason) then all your clients will have to change too.

AOP may work for you, but I think it'll be non-intuitive, and I don't think it'll be particularly resilient in the face of code changes.

My *preferred* solution in this sort of scenario is to follow your observer idea. Clients A and B can *both* register listeners and then run code upon changes registered by your server class. You'll probably find that you have to issue events for most (all?) state changes, and perhaps make other entities in your system available (via a supported API) for your clients. As it stands, it sounds like your requirements are pretty vague, and I would do something simple for the moment and see what transpires.

Answer (score -1):

For blending, make a class called FooBlender. Where Foo is the interface. It will have a list off Foo. For each method call, get the list of what the other classes return. Then return the average or blend of that list.